# How to install System.Reactive extensions in a Visual Studio 2012 solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, system.reactive

Visual Studio 2012 has nuget version 2.8.60318.667, that is not compatible with Reactive.Extensions 3.1.1.

If copy manually System.Reactive.* packages into the packages directory of my solution, when I launch the package manager from the Visual Studio UI, and I browse for installed package: instead of habing the list of installed package the following error is displayed:

[image: error with System.Reactive packages installed]
'System.Reactive.Core' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Reactive.Interfaces'.
nugeterror

If I install package with de package manager command:
install-package System.Reactive
the following error is displayed:
The 'System.Reactive 3.1.1' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer I got from the support [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/324):

<<
*If you cannot use the System.Reactive. packages, as a temporary workaround you can manually install the old Rx-Main package from the Package Manager Console (I think this is the right arguments):*

```
Install-Package Rx-Main -Version 2.2.5
```

*Unfortunately we are unable to support older versions of NuGet, due to the packaging changes required to support .NET Standard.*>>

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately VS2012 is 2 versions behind (2015 and 2013). VS2017 is nearly out (in RC) and there are free community editions, or you can use alternatives like VS Code. Time to move off a 5yr old product?

Comment: Yes, buying a new version is in the pipe. I cannot use community editions in our company. I use VS code for web projects but I cannot use it for visual studio solutions with several projects.
I thank you very much for your online book that helped me very much to understand Reactive.X.